# Как сверстать расписание с горизонтальной и вертикальной прокруткой?

Tags: html, css

Всем привет!

Никак не могу додумать, как такой блок сверстать, что бы прокрутка нормально работала? Что бы по горизонтали прокручивался весь блок с временной шкалой, а по вертикали только блок с расписанием.

Для скролла использую jScrollPane. Горизонтальная прокрутка работает, но вот с вертикальной уже проблемы, .т.к прокручивается весь блок (с временной шкалой)

Какая структура должна быть у HTML?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Просмотр кода страницы что показывает? Это таблица наверно. Столбики - часы. Строки - события. Ячейки, соответствующие времени  события закрашиваются. И даже растягиваются на всю продолжительность события colspan="n", где n - кол-во часов, отведённых на собитие.

Comment: Это макет просто, в принципе проблема только как с точки рения программинга сверстать блоки правильно. Ведь они по времени могут быть разные. Соответственно блоки по ширине варьируются.

Comment: Известно время события - следовательно известно сколько колонок до него `cols_before`, сколько колонок оно займёт `cols_inside`, и сколько останется после `cols_after`. В строке <tr> выводится  `cols_before` `<td>`, выводится широкая ячейка для события `<td colspan="cols_inside">`, выводится `cols_after` `<td/>` :       `<tr><td/>...<td colspan="cols_inside"></td><td/>...</tr>`

Comment: Буду пробовать, спасибо!